# Yocto autotools do_compile fails

Tags: linux, makefile, yocto, automake

I have created a recipe in my custom layer like this:

```
SUMMARY = "Mednafen is a portable, utilizing OpenGL and SDL, argument(command-line)-driven multi-system emulator."
HOMEPAGE = "https://mednafen.github.io/"
SRC_URI = "https://mednafen.github.io/releases/files/${PN}-${PV}.tar.xz"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "7be60dd12edf8d61537f5598957e2884"

FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"

DEPENDS += " zlib libsndfile1 libsdl2"

LICENSE = "GPL-2.0"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYING;md5=b234ee4d69f5fce4486a80fdaf4a4263"

S = "${WORKDIR}/${PN}"

inherit autotools-brokensep gettext
```

But when I try to create a minimal image I get this error message:

```
ERROR: mednafen-1.27.1-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: mednafen-1.27.1-r0 do_compile: Execution of '/home/cihan/Desktop/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mednafen/1.27.1-r0/temp/run.do_compile.14150' failed with exit code 1:
Making all in po
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/cihan/Desktop/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mednafen/1.27.1-r0/mednafen/po'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/cihan/Desktop/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mednafen/1.27.1-r0/mednafen/po'
Making all in intl
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/cihan/Desktop/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mednafen/1.27.1-r0/mednafen/intl'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'libgnuintl.@INTL_LIBTOOL_SUFFIX_PREFIX@a', needed by 'all-no-yes'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/cihan/Desktop/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mednafen/1.27.1-r0/mednafen/intl'
Makefile:452: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
WARNING: /home/cihan/Desktop/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mednafen/1.27.1-r0/temp/run.do_compile.14150:1 exit 1 from 'exit 1'

ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/cihan/Desktop/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mednafen/1.27.1-r0/temp/log.do_compile.14150
```

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong? Btw, I work on dunfell branch and thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always better to use ready-made recipes instead of handling all the dependencies, building options, patches...etc by your self. The [mednafen](https://github.com/sergioprado/meta-game-emulators/blob/dunfell/recipes-multi/mednafen/mednafen_1.24.3.bb) recipe for dunfell branch is defined here under `meta-game-emulators`:
https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/132957/

You need to clone this layer and add it to your bblayers, then try to rebuild again. if you need another version of mednafen (particularly 1.27.1 mentioned in your question) then try to use the recipe for version 1.24.3 as the base for your custom recipe. This will make things easier for you.

Comment: Thanks, when I looked at the meta-game-emulators I didn't notice the mednafen recipe. I will use it